# Como dar permisos para conectarse a un BD

Tags: permisos

Tengo una laptop que se esta conectando por IP a la maquina donde se encuentra todo el proyecto, al hacer un nuevo registro este se debe visualizar en una tabla, pero aparece este error:

> Error SQLSTATE[HY000] [1130] Host 'TIJD0091.eas-tj.com' is not allowed
>   to connect to this MariaDB server

Al parecer debo de darle permisos para que pueda acceder a la Base de Datos.

Como puedo arreglar eso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creas un usuario que es el que vas a usar para conectarte

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'192.168.0.12’ IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Con el comando `GRANT` asignas permisos a ese usuario en la base de datos indicada :

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dstabaseName.* TO 'USERNAME'@'192.168.0.12’ 
IDENTIFIED BY 'password'
```

Coloca en lugar de `localhost` la ip del equipo.

Como bien me lo recuerdan al final es hacer

FLUSH PRIVILEGES

Para refrescar y usar

Comment: no olvidarse del `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` para empezar a usarlo de inmediato